# batch script error using a for loop to populate an array of filenames: ) was unexpected at this time

Tags: arrays, batch-file, for-loop, runtime-error, dir

I'm stuck.

I've tried to simplify the code and have used Rob van der Woude's `LogBatch.bat` debugger. That helped me narrow the problem to a `for` loop that populates an array of file names by performing a `dir` search within the `for` command. It appears to run as long as there are file names that match. When no file names match, or when it runs out of matches, I get the error.

.

Error

> ) was unexpected at this time.

.

Code Snippet

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A "filecount=-1"
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "C:\files\Spreadsheets\TestFiles\ExportedData*.csv"') do (
    set /A "filecount=filecount+1"
    set "filematches[!filecount!]=%%i"
)
```

.

Sample files

> ExportedData12-31-15.csv
>
> ExportedData2015-12-31.csv

.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I would appreciate an explanation as well. I'd like to understand the problem.

Also, if there is an alternate approach to populate the array with the file names, I'd be interested in suggestions.

Please limit answers only to solutions that use native `CMD.exe` batch scripts and localized variables. (Please avoid global variables.) Please do not suggest any `.NET`, `vbscript`, or `jscript`/`javascript` solutions.

The directory path is fixed. The example path has no spaces, but I'd like the option of handling spaces without reverting down to `8.3` file names.

The example file names should adhere to the convention of FileTitle*DATE*.ext.

Thank you.

=========================================================

EDIT: Feb. 2nd, 2016

Here is the complete batch script. It is unfinished and for testing, I have commented out the `ren` (rename), `del` (delete), and `echo stuff to >> logfile.log`. I am providing 3 versions on pastebin...

@Magoo @CoveGeek @Mofi [Links here](http://pastebin.com/bLjJdeHn)

I don't know if the full source will help, but I hope it will. I was hesitant given the length and the multiple versions.

Comment: The snippet you've posted doesn't appear to generate the error of which you've complained. I believe a larger section of code is warranted.

Comment: As mentioned above the code snip you pasted here does nothing more than save a bunch of env values. With the SETLOCAL command, the values are not accessible outside of the current batch file. More context is required.

Comment: And you can use also `for %%i in ("C:\files\Spreadsheets\TestFiles\ExportedData*.csv") do (` as there is really no need to use command __DIR__ for this task as __FOR__ can search itself for files matching a pattern.

Comment: Here is the complete batch script. It is unfinished and for testing, I have commented out the `ren` (rename), `del` (delete), and `echo stuff to >> logfile.log`. I am providing 3 versions on pastebin...

Comment: @Magoo

See the edit to the main post dated Feb. 2nd, 2016

(Sorry for the multiple posts, The site kept throwing objections.)

Comment: @CoveGeek

See the edit to the main post dated Feb. 2nd, 2016

(Sorry for the multiple posts, The site kept throwing objections.)

Comment: @Mofi

See the edit to the main post dated Feb. 2nd, 2016

(Sorry for the multiple posts, The site kept throwing objections.)

Comment: @AntyalTennyson You should replace all `[` and `]` by `"` because `[` and `]` have no special meaning for string comparisons, but `"` makes it possible to compare strings with space or other special characters inside the compared strings like round brackets. The main mistake you made is putting labels within body of __FOR__. This is not possible and confuses command processor resulting in the syntax error message. You have to rewrite the code and use subroutines or an appropriate IF - ELSE structure instead of labels within body of __FOR__.